# Accessibility role for button that links out of the app in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, accessibility, roles, talkback

I’m creating a button in compose that redirects the user to the browser. According to accessibility guidelines and our auditor we need to mark this button as “Link” so that in talkback it will anounce the text on the button followed by link (being the role, not in the label).
for example: “open in browser, link”

- note it is not allowed to just use “button” even though the button text specifies it will open the browser

Looking at the [Compose documentation about the Role class](https://developer.android.google.cn/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/semantics/Role) it seems Link is not an option (It only contains the roles “Button”, “Checkbox”, “DropdownList”, “Image”, “RadioButton”, “Switch”, “Tab”).
Not what I’m looking for.

Is there a different way to mark the button as a link so we can pass the guidelines?

Comment: If there is no role, the documentation says "If an exact role is not listed in Role, this property should not be set and the framework will automatically resolve it." So I think a button is fine and you can set the content description to either read the button text + domain name or "this will open a hyperlink"